# How do I get alt-tab to cycle through all open windows on GNOME Classic?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-classic

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with "Gnome classic (no effects)" at login. Using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> cycles between windows on current desktop. How can I set it to cycle through ALL open windows?

---

Well, I have done as proposed, here is what happened: when I pressed Alt+Tab, it still showed only window icons from current desktop. Furthermore, I could only switch between the two most recently used windows with a single Tab press. Releasing the Tab and pressing again closed the window chooser.

Another try after logout-login gave another result: pressing Alt+Tab just showed the main menu.

More ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

Under "System *Settings* **>** *Keyboard* **>** *Shortcuts* **>** *System* **>** *Show the activities overview*" you can set <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, which then should cycle through all open windows and applications, on all workspaces, no matter if active/in use or inactive.

I tested it in Gnome-Classic and it works fine! Please let us know, if that solves your problem!

[image: sh]

---

**Edit:** Gnome Shell Extensions that might do the job:

- [alternatetab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/15/alternatetab/)
- [coverflow-alt-tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/97/coverflow-alt-tab/)
- [windows-alt-tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/38/windows-alt-tab/)
- [force-thumbnails-on-alt-tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/516/force-thumbnails-on-alt-tab/)
- [power-alt-tab](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/58/power-alt-tab/)
- [alt-tab-workspace](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/310/alt-tab-workspace/)

Comment: No, this did not work for me.

Comment: didnt work for me as well .. :(

Comment: What exactly did not work for you? Years later: The newer Ubuntu OS Versions do support this function natively.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem.

Looking in **System Settings** → **Keyboard** → **Shortcuts** → **Navigation**, I realized that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> combination was assigned to two different options:

- Moving through applications
- Change windows directly

(My system is in Spanish, so I hope the translations are accurate enough)

Assigning a new combination to the last one solved my problem! I hope this helps you.

Comment: didnt work for me . I am on 12.04, 32bit with gnome-classic settings.

Comment: Working on Ubuntu 18.04.2 , the name of Option is Switch Windows

Comment: Thank you for this. I don't know why it didn't dawn on me to look in the Gnome keyboard shortcut settings for a difference between "Switch Applications" and "Switch Windows".

Answer (score 7):

A bug has been reported to Launchpad on this issue. Until it's resolved, install Compiz Config Settings Manager, then use the "Scale" settings there to set ALT-TAB as you want it. Works nicely, actually.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to the bug report? Was it assigned?

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776

Comment: The question was about Gnome Classic (no effects) which uses metacity, not compiz.

Answer (score 3):

What I did:

```
Alt+F2 -> dconf-editor -> Enter
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-applications ['<Super>Tab']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-applications-backwards ['<Shift><Super>Tab']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-windows ['<Alt>Tab']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-windows-backwards ['<Shift><Alt>Tab']
```

**Note, this is the default:**

```
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-applications ['<Super>Tab','<Alt>Tab']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-applications-backwards ['<Shift><Super>Tab','<Shift><Alt>Tab']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-windows ['']
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings -> switch-windows-backwards ['']
```