# Gnome classic Alt-Tab doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-classic, application-switcher

The simple keyboard combination of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between applications doesn't work.

I have followed [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112595/how-do-i-get-alt-tab-to-cycle-through-all-open-windows-on-gnome-classic) answer but it doesn't answer the question as I want to switch to another application, not display applications and then have to select it via the mouse as it defeats the purpose of the quick switch to the other application.

There is also mention of updating the Keyboard shortcut settings. My keyboard combination is set to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> in the shortcut section and it doesn't switch applications. Seems the setting is ignored as I changed it to another keyboard combo and it just doesn't switch applications.

Comment: Are you using "gnome classic no effects"?

Comment: @seth No, just Gnome Classic

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Seems Application Switching is turned of by default.

To activate it you need to run the following command

```
ccsm
```

That will bring up *CompizConfig Settings Manager*.

- Go to the *Window Management* section.
- Check off ✔ *Application Switcher*.

Then the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> will work.

Require installation of the `compiz-plugins-extra` package.

Comment: For what it's worth, this option seems to be crashing my Gnome. I used mace's suggestion and activated the static application switcher, which now works beautifully.

Comment: How can this be done programmatically (i.e., a script) or on the command line?

Comment: for Ubuntu 14 and up
the package that contains ccsm is actually: compizconfig-settings-manager
The compiz-plugins-extra is not required.

Comment: It works. Still, once done, I realised having it disabled on my ubuntu desktop makes sense, since it looks so ugly. While "Super+W" is a good substitute for switching for windows

Comment: +1 for `compiz-plugins-extra`

Answer (score 9):

[The solution in Meer Borg's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/308199/22949) made my computer very slow.

I instead checked the:

> ✔ Static Application Switcher

That also solves this problem.

Comment: yeahh this thing worked for me too

Comment: What is `Static Application Switcher`? How to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Static Application Switcher` made my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> work, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> was somehow bound to a different application switcher, which meant that I could not go back and forth by keeping the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key down, and alternating between <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I finally managed to get it working by removing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> from `switch-applications-backward`:

> gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
>   switch-applications-backward "['<Shift><Super>Tab']"

Answer (score 0):

install,

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

## if you didnt install plugin you wont be able to see `application switcher`

type `ccsm` in terminal or do `alt+F2` search ccsm

and select `Window management` , check (enable) `application switcher`  checkbox.

if it prompt for conflicts, say resolve conflicts and select things which is selected which is **set anyway**

done..

now you can do `alt+tab`

you can change this shortcut in same `ccsm`,

-> Scroll down or filter to "Ubuntu Unity Plugin". 
-> Choose the tab "Switcher". 
-> click alt-tab and shift-alt-tab key bindings. ("Key to switch to the previous window in the Switcher")
Click the "Back" button.