# Alt-Tab is not switching between manually installed packages and existing packages

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, ccsm

I am using gnome-classic on vnc4server and ubuntu version is Ubuntu-16.04. Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> is not switching windows between manually installed packages like Google Chrome and existing installed packages. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, the underlying window contour shows but the window doesn't activate. I have attached here a screenshot.

[image: screenshot window not activating]

But it works fine between pre-installed softwares like Firefox, Terminal window and Text editor etc. I already tried installing CompizConfig Settings Manager mentioned here
[Gnome classic Alt-Tab doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/282573/gnome-classic-alt-tab-doesnt-work/308199#308199)
or here [How do I get alt-tab to cycle through all open windows on GNOME Classic?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112595/how-do-i-get-alt-tab-to-cycle-through-all-open-windows-on-gnome-classic?rq=1)

If anyone give a pointer to how to solve this problem, will be great.