# No Alt + Tab in 14.04 Gnome Flashback session?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys, compiz, gnome-classic

I've just upgraded to 14.04 and installed the Gnome Flashback Session.  However, Alt + Tab doesn't bring up an application switcher.  I've tried Compiz Config Settings Manager, but there are no options for the switcher outside of the Unity menus.  Is there a work around for this?  I much prefer Classic / Flashback over Unity...

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

First try through the

- **Basic settings**

`Go to 'Applications','System Tools','System Settings'`

`Click 'Keyboard'`

`Click the 'Shortcuts Tab'`

`Click 'Navigation' on the left`

`In the right-hand pane click on 'Switch applications' and press Alt-Tab to assign that as the accelerator.`

EDIT: It's been marked in comments, citing "The first method alone does not work. The compiz plugins are definitely necessary!". I can not check it at the moment, now I just put this comment here.

Or can be fixed by installing

- **Compiz**

and enabling `Static Application Switcher`

```
sudo apt-get install compiz
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

you might need to install `compiz-plugins-extra` as well and then

```
ccsm
```

[image]

Comment: @NoTime you will not need to run `ccsm` as a `root`, works without `sudo`.

Comment: When I try to install compiz-plugins-extras, I get this output: "Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 compiz-plugins-extra : Depends: compiz-plugins but it is not going to be installed"

Any ideas?

Comment: As it says you need have `compiz-plugins` installed. I will add it to the answer after your feedback with success. So, now `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins` and then try again for extra. And if it is going to be mess again, try via `Synaptic` it easier resolve all dependencies (`sudo apt-get install synaptic` and the `sudo synaptic` and put `compiz` in search)

Comment: I wasn't able to install compiz-plugins or compiz-plugins-extras through terminal or synaptic.  Same output.  However, I tried purging and reinstalling the flashback session, now Alt+Tab switches as it should.  I still can't install compiz-plugins or extras, but it works.  I don't understand why, or what happened, but, I guess this is solved?  Thanks, Ruslan!

Comment: compiz-plugins-extra did the trick!

Comment: The first method alone does not work. The compiz plugins are definitely necessary!

Comment: @peschü okay, I added your point to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Static Application switcher was not working for me. Nor was the option for Navigation in System Settings. Neither did a combination of both. But Shift switcher did work, so I got that going for me. So thanks!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/956318/413480  this `dconf-editor` helped me.