# Make Ubuntu not Club same type of tasks

Tags: 14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. When I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch windows, Ubuntu club the same type of tasks.

For eg. If I have 2 Chrome windows, and 2 Firefox windows open, And I do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

I see only 2 and not 4 options. Now when I stay on a single <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> option for a few seconds it then shows me the windows inside it.

That is not the case in linux mint. Linux Mint shows all the tabs for all the programs running when we do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there a way, to do the same in Ubuntu --- not make it club the tasks when doing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Comment: Are you on unity or gnome ?

Comment: possuble duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/84880/how-can-i-make-alt-tab-browse-through-all-my-windows-without-grouping-them and also http://askubuntu.com/questions/112595/how-do-i-get-alt-tab-to-cycle-through-all-open-windows-on-gnome-classic